# C#: Generic Inherited Factories

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class that takes a single generic argument.  I then have several classes that inherit from this base class.  Is there a simple way for the child classes to inherent a factory from the base class?

Example

```
class BaseClass<T>
{
     T Value {get; set;}
     string Name {get; set;}

     public static BaseClass<T> Factory(T Value)
     {
        return new BaseClass<T>(Value); 
     }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass<int>
{
     public void Test()
     {
         // I want this below to work
         // but Factory() returns a BaseClass
         ChildClass bs = ChildClass.Factory(10);
     }
}
```

I've noted in the code what I want to work.  I can think of one way to overcome this, by adding an implicit operator to either BaseClass or SubClass that converts from BaseClass to ChildClass.

I can also just explicitly add the Factory to ChildClass but that defeats the point of inheritance.

Is there a better, more standardized way of doing this?

Comment: Why not just type-cast inside of `Test()`?

Comment: I don't want the classes to require casting for functionality.  If I'm going to do casting, I'm going to make it an implicit cast.

Comment: Is `Factory()` supposed to be static?

Comment: @Mark: Probably.  Yes.  I don't really care though, I don't want it to impede a more nuanced answer.

Comment: Your `Factory` method is declared as an instance method, but is used as though it were a static method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
class BaseClass<T, K> where K : BaseClass<T, K>, new()
{
    T Value { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    public static K Factory(T value)
    {
        return new K { Value = value };
    }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass<int, ChildClass>
{
    public void Test()
    {
        ChildClass cs = Factory(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't compile because the compiler cannot infer `ChildClass`, not to mention you didn't specify `BaseClass`. In your code, it should be `BaseClass<int, ChildClass>.Factory(10)`

Comment: @Kobi: It does compile.  I do this kind of thing all the time in generic inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: @siride - You're right, I missed the part `Factory` is inherited. Oops (weird, I do remember testing it `:P`). It does change the class signature though... Seems to work very nicely though, if you call `ChildClass.Factory(1)`, so maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: This is magical. I don't care that it changes the signature.  I'll mark this as answered tomorrow, I'm curious if there are any other ways of doing this.

Comment: @Mike: it's a kind of CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern).  The base class does all the work and the type information is passed along via inheritance from more specific child classes.  Eric Lippert is against it, but I disagree with his stance and reasoning.

Comment: One reason against this is that it's still possible to say `class ChildClass : BaseClass<int,OtherClass>` and have a factory for `OtherClass` from within `BaseClass`.

Comment: @Mark Cidade: if it's a prblem you can check `typeof(K) == typeof(this)` in static contructor of `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer your question since you have described what you are trying to do, but not why. Hence I got to try to guess what you want.

I would not put the factory method in the same class as in the other answer or your question. How would you handle inheritance for once? It works for the two levels that you have. But what if you want to extend `ChildClass`?

Instead I would create a generic factory used for the object creation. Implement it has a singleton wrapped around a factory interface to be able to easy extend it or swap the implementation.

```
class MyFactory
{
    private static IMyFactory _instance;
    public static void Assign(IMyFactory factory) { _instance = factory; }
    public static T Create<T>() { return _instance.Create<T>(); }
}

interface IMyFactory
{
    T Create<T>();
}
class MyFactoryImp : IMyFactory
{
    //do whatever needed in here
    public T Create<T>(){ return new T(); }
}


class BaseClass<T>
{
     T Value {get; set;}
     string Name {get; set;}
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass<int>
{
     public void Test()
     {
         ChildClass bs = MyFactory.Create<ChildClass>(10);
     }
}

// start with this, you can easily switch implementation
MyFactory.Assign(new MyFactoryImp());
```

The other obvious answer would be to start using a Inversion Of Control container, for example autofac.